# chunk code plot from rmd file not shown in the post of blogdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

When I use the blogdown and hugo academic create a website, one example post created by rmd file (2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown) has chunk code, but the plot of this chunk code did not show in the post [see here](https://qingzeng.netlify.app/blog/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown/). I can see the chunk code created figures in the figure_html folder though

besides, when insert image from addin in rstudio, it automatically provides a path: static/blog/2020-11-09-creating-a-website/index_files/1.JPG, however the image does not show in the post. When I use a path static/blog/2020-11-09-creating-a-website/1.JPG, it works. What could be wrong with the index_files folder?